# How to install Percona 5.7 with TokuDB from tar file

Tags: mysql, plugins, tar, percona, tokudb

How use Percona 5.7 with engine TokuDB using the tar file?

I want to install the binary that can be found here: https://www.percona.com/downloads/Percona-Server-5.7/LATEST/

I have done the following steps:

```
 mkdir -p ./service
 mkdir -p ./service/mysqld
 mkdir -p ./service/mysqld/data
 tar xfz Percona-Server-5.7.28-31-Linux.x86_64.ssl102.tar.gz --strip-components 1 -C ./service/mysqld
./service/mysqld/bin/mysqld  --initialize-insecure --basedir=./service/mysqld --datadir=./service/mysqld/data --user=<my-user>

 mysqld --default-storage-engine=tokudb --user <my-user>
```

Not sure if the above is correct and I don't know what the next step should be. I can not find any guide how to do this, only how to do it with packet manager. Any one have an idea how to continue?

Do I need to manually download the tokudb plugin or is it included? How do I start the mysql daemon?

Note I don't want to use docker or any packet manager. This I know how to do. I want to be able to install mysql under the service folder, so I can easy remove it when I'm done.

Comment: It's usually easier to install linux software with the package manager of your distribution, in the link provided you can follow their instructions there, by the way, this question probably will be better answered if you post it in the serverfault site as here is a forum for software developers

Answer (score 0):

You just have to follow the official Percona documentation:

https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-server/5.7/installation.html#installing-percona-server-from-a-binary-tarball

Answer (score 0):

You should not use mysqld directly to start mysql, instead use: mysqld_safe
if you go into the MySQL dir after unpacket and run:

> ./bin/mysqld_safe --ledir=./bin/ --basedir=. --datadir=./data

Then to load TokuDB you can run ps-admin, this requiere root access, since you want to install it in a folder I guess you don't have it. So then a better option is to connect to your mysql server using mysql client and run:

```
INSTALL PLUGIN tokudb SONAME 'ha_tokudb.so';
INSTALL PLUGIN tokudb_file_map SONAME 'ha_tokudb.so';
INSTALL PLUGIN tokudb_fractal_tree_info SONAME 'ha_tokudb.so';
INSTALL PLUGIN tokudb_fractal_tree_block_map SONAME 'ha_tokudb.so';
INSTALL PLUGIN tokudb_trx SONAME 'ha_tokudb.so';
INSTALL PLUGIN tokudb_locks SONAME 'ha_tokudb.so';
INSTALL PLUGIN tokudb_lock_waits SONAME 'ha_tokudb.so';
INSTALL PLUGIN tokudb_background_job_status SONAME 'ha_tokudb.so';
```

Now it should be possible to use the engine TokuDB.

However if you need more help checkout:
https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-server/LATEST/tokudb/tokudb_installation.html

I agree the instructions for this is confusing if you do not use the packet installer for the Linux distributions. Good thing with this is that its easy to remove if you fail you can just remove the folder.

If you have any problems let me know?